# "Displaying Triangles" Intro to C# textbook exercise

Tags: c#, for-loop

I have discovered: when it comes to logic I am an imbecile. [Here's an imgur upload of problem I am ridiculously stuck on.](http://i.imgur.com/DlyNFl1.png)

I'm not wrapping my head around the logic of the solution. I see that I'm meant to use For loops in order to display lines of asterisks beginning with 1 and ending with 10 (for the first part at least), but I'm not getting how to increment the string output itself.

I had an idea to create a variable with the value of the loop multiplied by the string, hoping it would display the loopCounter * asteriskString, but that's not possible.

Any help is appreciated. My logic skills need work.

Comment: Your question asking needs some too... See [Why is "Can Someone Help Me? not an "actual" question](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question/284237#284237) Hint, you haven't asked a question yet :)

Comment: "increment the string output itself" - do you mean the indention? The space is a character just as the asterisk.

Comment: Can you let me know if my answer was acceptable?

Comment: @YoryeNathan thank you for your response. I was referring to both the asterisk and the space, yes. It turns out I needed to iterate a loop that displayed asterisks and/or spaces.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Please forgive my misunderstanding, but can you please tell me how the question was inadequate. I read over the linked thread and it still seems fine to me. I received a helpful reply and the problem was solved.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET If you have a moment, since I have your attention: I'd like to give back to StackOverflow if I can, but I'm still getting used to the site. Is there a section for beginner questions such as these (kiddie table if you will =P) where someone like myself might be of some use?

Comment: To your first question, at a base level this question was inadequate because you *never asked a question*. Read the whole thing carefully, you say "You are confused" and that "any help is appreciated", but there is *no question here*. The second issue is that you have shown no attempt at solving it. You get kudos for describing some of the stuff you've thought about though. Both of those combined mean that the only answer is **the entire code for the problem** which... is the answer you got. This isn't very useful for future visitors/readers, so the question isn't a very good one.

Comment: To your second question. No, there is no section devoted to "newbie" questions. The best way to find questions to answer is to crawl the active tab on a tag you are knowledgeable in, find an interesting looking question, and answer it! Thanks for wanting to give back!

Comment: Ah, ok I see. I noticed in the Can Someone Help Me thread there was an emphasis on searchability in posts, something I think is brilliant about this site and others like it. I tried to achieve that in my post, specifically in the title, imagining how a student with the same problem might search. Also I noted in what ways exactly I was unable to find a solution to the problem when I searched initially. I was hoping to include some code in my post but I quickly realized the real problem was with the fundamental logic--I was unable to even formulate a basic algorithm!

Comment: It would be really great if there were a "Stack 101" for absolute newbs like myself. I don't mind making a fool out of myself due to simple ignorance, but I do feel bad being a hindrance to users attempting to do real work. Thank you for your time.

Comment: Thanks for listening so well to the feedback you are getting! Something I think you are perhaps misunderstanding is what we mean by search-ability. More than likely, *no one* is going to be searching for "how to draw a triangle in C#" unless they have the same assignment as you. Instead, they might search for "Incrementing spaces in a loop" (for example). Thats what my post means when it says "ask about programming problems, not implementing features". Basically, this post is not quite ready for Stack Overflow, you needed to break the problem down a bit more.

Comment: As to Stack 101, the reason we haven't done that is we want to encourage  *great* simple questions. This one isn't there, but just because a question is "easy" for an expert to answer doesn't make it bad. Splitting the knowledge base up like that isn't really making the internet a better place. Get some rep (editing is a good start) and come by chat sometime. I'd love to help you learn how to write a better question!

Comment: Oh the question was fine, as the perfect solution it garnered proves more than adequately, but I appreciate the opinions and the conversation. Unfortunately beginners aren't experts or there wouldn't be problems in the world! =P Take care.

Comment: @ZachHiggins The answer you got was *not good at all*. Read around on Meta a bit, and you'll understand the code-only answers are not exactly encouraged. I'm glad you got help, but this question is not going to make the internet a better place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not the cleanest solution but this will get your results. Read through it and figure out how to make it better.

```
using System;    

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{    
   class Program
{        
    static int triangles = 4;
    static int lines = 10;

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {           
        for (int i = 1; i <= triangles; i++)
        {
            if (i==1||i==4)
            {
                for (int j = 1; j <= lines; j++)                    
                    writeAstrix(i, j);                    
            }
            else
            {
                for (int j = lines; j > 0; j--)                    
                    writeAstrix(i, j);
            }              
            Console.WriteLine();
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private static void writeAstrix(int i, int j)
    {           
        if (i == 3||i==4)
            makeSpacers(j);

        while (j > 0)
        {
            Console.Write('*');
            j--;
        }
        Console.WriteLine();
    }

    private static void makeSpacers(int iterate)
    {
        int spacers = lines - iterate;
        while (spacers > 0)
        {
            Console.Write(' ');
            spacers--;
        }
    }
 }    
}
```

Comment: My sincerest apologies for the slow reply. I chose to step through the entire program manually, and it helped.

The loop in Main iterates each triangle. For triangles 1 and 4, in which asterisks are incremented, a For loop is called which increments j. For triangles 2 and 3, j is initialized to the line length and decremented to display asterisks.

If spacers need to be written, j is sent to makeSpacers which calculates and displays them.

Thank you for your time and again I apologize if it seems like I was ignoring you and wasting your time, I simply needed to find the time!